# derivative of power series, and its supremum

Tags: derivatives, power-series, supremum-and-infimum

Let $\{ a_n \}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Assume $g(x) = \sum a_k x^k$ converges on $(-r, r)$ for some $r>0$, then there exist $a, b >0$ and a neighbourhood $N \subset (-r,r)$ of $0$ such that "for any $n \in \mathbb N$ "

$$ \sup_{x \in N} |g^{(n)} (x) |  \leq ab^n n!.$$

It is obvious that when $n = 0$, $g^{(n)}$ attains its maximum on a small closed interval $[-\delta, \delta].$
I think, when differentiated, the exponent goes down by one, so the factorial of about $n$ comes out. How can I prove it regolously? Please help me, thank you.

**edit**

I want to prove the following part

> then there exist $a, b >0$ and a neighbourhood $N \subset (-r,r)$ of $0$ such that "for any $n \in \mathbb N$ "

> $$ \sup_{x \in N} |g^{(n)} (x) |  \leq ab^n n!.$$

Comment: How can you prove **what**???

Comment: What is $n$ in your statement ? Are $a, b, N$ independent from $n$?

Comment: soryy for the confusion, I edited just now. @Faicon yes, a,b, N is independent from n.